# Trying to get white drop shadow of dark SVG Image

Tags: svg, svg-filters, dropshadow

I'm trying to put svg image that has a drop shadow. My homepage background color is pretty dark. So I would like to have a white drop-shadow of dark svg object.
Is that possible??

[the svg image looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o69t.png)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just recolor the blur to white before you composite it under your source graphic. like so:

```
<feGaussianBlur id="blur" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4"/>
<feColorMatrix id="recolor"  type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0" result="white-glow"/>

<!-- Merge the shadow with the original --> 
<feMerge> 
  <feMergeNode in="white-glow"/> 
  <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
</feMerge> 
</filter>
```

Comment: Thanks!! That works good for the color. I noticed that the stroke gets also blurred (I mean the vector lines are pixelized)... Isn't it possible to keep the stroke line sharp and add drop shadow  behind it??

Comment: Don't edit your original question - post another question as followup with the source code this time.